# Webstorm nodejs conventions spaces

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I read that the convention of node js of spaces is double spaces, but by default it is 4 spaces, how to configure it?

**It is:**

```
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
```

**should be this way:**

```
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a "convention" - that's called code style; and more specifically, it looks like it's the [NPM Coding Style](https://npmjs.org/doc/coding-style.html), as it's followed by lots of Node developers out there.

You can customize this easily by going to Settings -> Code Style -> JavaScript in WebStorm.

P.S.: I personally like a lot the [jQuery Code Style](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/) - it's more readable than any other.